# Show desktop on boot without HDMI cable

Tags: pi-4, hdmi

I'm using vnc viewer for my pi 4 and it says 'cannot currently show desktop', because, from what I assume, is the fact that if it doesn't have an HDMI connection when it boots, it won't show the desktop. Is there a way to make it show the desktop on boot whether or not there's an HDMI cable? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You shouldn't have to have an HDMI cable connected.  What are your hdmi settings in /boot/config.txt ?

Comment: and if you connect an HDMI cable the issue doesn't present itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use VNC without a display. Make sure you've followed all the [steps](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/) properly. If it still doesn't work try changing the resolution of your screen to 1280 x 720 or 1920 x 1080 by typing `sudo raspi-config` in the terminal.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. For some reason the default resolution would show the desktop!